# Python's re module mishandles backslash

Tags: python, regex

I am using Python's 3.3 *re* module. I want to change a document in which for emphasizing a word it is placed between asterisks into another in which the marks for the same emphasis are '{\em ...}' (the typesetting *ConTeXt* system).

For instance the sentence

```
Shakespeare wrote *Hamlet*.
```

should be transformed into

```
Shakespeare wrote {\em Hamlet}.
```

The following regular expression locates and extracts perfectly the required information:

```
>>> import re
>>> pc_em = re.compile(r'\*(.+?)\*')
>>> emph = 'Shakespeare wrote *Hamlet*.'
>>> m = pc_em.search( emph )
>>> m.group(1)
'Hamlet'
```

But I have been unable to find any way to perform the final replacement:

```
>>> pc_em.sub( r'{\em \g<1>}', emph )
'Shakespeare wrote {\\em Hamlet}.'
>>> pc_em.sub( r'{\\em \g<1>}', emph )
'Shakespeare wrote {\\em Hamlet}.'
>>> pc_em.sub( '{\\em \g<1>}', emph )
'Shakespeare wrote {\\em Hamlet}.'
```

Does somebody know how to get a single backslash inside the final braces or is this a bug?

Thanks in advance

Paco

Comment: I think your first replacement is actually working fine- try `print(pc_em.sub( r'{\em \g<1>}', emph ))` to see the actual text, rather than its string literal representation.

Comment: Hint:  what are the odds that a regexp package used by countless thousands of programmers for years mishandles backslashes, and you're the first person to notice?  Second hint:  your first guess was too high ;-)

Comment: I don't observe your result, neither in IDLE nor in a command line window. Your question is perplexing me. Moreover, when I do ``h = pc_em.sub( r'{\em \g<1>}', '*H*' )`` and then ``print h,len(h)``, I get ``{\em H} 7``.

Comment: @Tim Peters You are completely right, Tim: the probability is extremely small. But until yesterday I would have considered even smaller the probability that *Python* displayed as wrongly performed an operation it had done well and yet today I have to admit it as certain, thanks to your explanations. How inexhaustible is the human propensity to make things interesting!

Answer (score 7):

The replacement is working correctly. The interpreter is printing the representation of the string rather than the string itself, so the backslashes are escaped.

If you `print(pc_em.sub( r'{\em \g<1>}', emph))` you will see that it is correct.